# Is $X$ linearly Lindelöf?

Tags: general-topology

A space $X$ is linearly Lindelöf iff every open covering of $X$ contains a subcovering $\gamma$ such that the cofinality of $\gamma$ is countable.

We denote by $l(X)$ the Lindelöf degree of $X$, that is, the smallest infinite cardinal number $\tau$ such that from every open covering of $X$ one can choose a subcovering the cardinality of which does not exceed $\tau$.

My question is this:

Let $X$ be a topological space and $l(X)$ have a countable cofinality. Then is $X$ linearly Lindelöf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily.

Let $D$ be a discrete space of cardinality $\omega_\omega$, let $p$ be a point not in $D$, and let $X=D\cup\{p\}$. A set $U\subseteq X$ is a nbhd of $p$ iff $|X\setminus U|<\omega_\omega$. Clearly $\ell(X)\le|X|=\omega_\omega$. If $\omega<\kappa<\omega_\omega$, fix $A\subseteq D$ such that $|A|=\kappa$; then $\big\{\{x\}:x\in A\big\}\cup\{X\setminus A\}$ is an open cover of $X$ of cardinality $\kappa$ having no proper subcover, so $\ell(X)=\omega_\omega$, which has countable cofinality.

Now let $A\subseteq D$ be such that $|A|=\omega_1$, and enumerate $A=\{x_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}$. For each $\eta<\omega_1$ let $U_\eta=(X\setminus A)\cup\{x_\xi:\xi<\eta\}$; then $\{U_\eta:\eta<\omega_1\}$ is an open cover of $X$ linearly ordered by $\subseteq$ that has no countable subcover, so $X$ is not linearly Lindelöf.